# Regex for a set of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, grep

Hi Guys I am using ruby 1.8.7 and I need a regular expression to split a string into words.
Below are the examples

```
SSAI @ 37C final OD=2.3 @ 16.6h, 492mg/3L, 0% soluble
ss autoinduction @37C overnight, OD=2.1@16.6hrs, 487mg/3L, 70%soluble
AF 0.3mM IPTG induce@10C 24hrs OD=0.2@5.6h, 19mg/3L, 50%soluble
AF, 0.3mM IPTG @ 37C, IND @ OD 0.55 @ 4hrs, 476mg/12L, 0% soluble
```

This is the split (with respect to the first example)

- `SSAI(everything before the first @)`
- `37(integers after the first @)`
- `2.3(float before the second @)`
- `16.6(float after the second @)`
- `492 and 3(pattern mg/*L)`
- `0(before the %)`

I have a set of strings with the same patterns which I would like to run the regex on and import into a database.

Comment: Please provide more information about your string structure. Will it always look like the above? What are the triggers for detecting each substring?

Comment: please give at least one more example of input/output so we can see what the pattern exactly is. Also: what have you tried so far? Where is the actual problem? Few people are willing to just do your work.

Comment: And you are sure that the `3` in `492mg/3L` should not be matched?

Comment: @p11y I have modified the question sorry about the vague example earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick for all of the inputs. The idea is to perform the operation in two steps. First split the fields by '/@/', save the first one for later, and then search for decimals in the rest of the fields.

```
first, *rest = str.split(/@/)
rest.map!{|s| s.scan(/\d+\.?\d*/)}.flatten!

first
#=> "SSAI "

rest
#=> ["37", "2.3", "16.6", "492", "3", "0"]
```

full example:

```
def extract(source)
  first, *rest = str.split(/@/)
  rest.map!{|s| s.scan(/\d+\.?\d*/)}.flatten!
  [first, *rest]
end

input = "SSAI @ 37C final OD=2.3 @ 16.6h, 492mg/3L, 0% soluble
ss autoinduction @37C overnight, OD=2.1@16.6hrs, 487mg/3L, 70%soluble
AF 0.3mM IPTG induce@10C 24hrs OD=0.2@5.6h, 19mg/3L, 50%soluble
AF, 0.3mM IPTG @ 37C, IND @ OD 0.55 @ 4hrs, 476mg/12L, 0% soluble"

input.lines.each do |line|
  p extract(line)
end

# ["SSAI ", "37", "2.3", "16.6", "492", "3", "0"]
# ["ss autoinduction ", "37", "2.1", "16.6", "487", "3", "70"]
# ["AF 0.3mM IPTG induce", "10", "24", "0.2", "5.6", "19", "3", "50"]
# ["AF, 0.3mM IPTG ", "37", "0.55", "4", "476", "12", "0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan

```
 > s = "SSAI @ 37C final OD=2.3 @ 16.6h, 492mg/3L, 0% soluble"
 => "SSAI @ 37C final OD=2.3 @ 16.6h, 492mg/3L, 0% soluble"

 > s.scan(/(.*?) @ (\d+)C .*?OD=([\d.]+) @ ([\d.]+)h, (\d+)mg.*?, (\d+)%/)
 => [["SSAI", "37", "2.3", "16.6", "492", "0"]]
```

Or, use that regex and then set $1, $2, etc...

Comment: This is wonderful something I could start with. Thanks @Philip Hallstrom

Comment: I think the regex here is a bit too specific. It doesn't look like it works for the fourth line in the example.

Comment: Yep, I am trying to make it as generic as I can. I didnt know how to get started because this is the first time I am working with regular expressions. The example above gave me an idea of how it works. @Coenwulf

Answer (score 0):

This will produce subgroups for each desired set. However, it can't put both the 492 and 3 from the fifth set into one subgroup so those become the fifth and sixth respectively and pushes the % soluble to the seventh submatch:

```
/^(.*?) @ (\d+)\D+(\d+\.\d+) @ (\d+\.\d+)\D+(\d+)mg\/(\d+)L\D*(\d+)%/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with.
If anyone has any suggestions please shoot.
Thanks

```
 /(.*?)@{1}(\d+).*(\d+\.\d+)@(\d+\.\d+).*?(\d+)mg\/(\d+).*?(\d+)%/
```

Comment: {1} is not required after the first @. the .* between the second and third groups will cause a problem if the float in the third group is 10 or higher since .* is greedy. Using \D+ (one or more non-digit characters) there instead would fix it. Other than that it look viable.